# group and average replicates from a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of different samples and technical replicates (AA.1, AA.2, AA.3). Each full sample set (all sample technical replicates) has a measurement, var3, and is repeated for a different var2 (X, Y, or Z). So in total, I have (# of samples)*(# of technical replicates)*(number of var2) measurements (all possible combinations of var1 x var2 repeated 3 times).

```
data.frame(
  var1=rep(rep(c('AA.1', 'AA.2', 'AA.3', 'BB.1', 'BB.2', 'BB.3'), each=3), 2),
  var2=rep(c('X', 'Y'), each=18),
  var3=sample(20:40, 36, replace=TRUE)
)
```

For each var2, I want to average each individual sample's technical replicate. I would like to do this by creating a new data frame that lists the sample name as the row names and 3 columns are the 3 technical replicates. Then I can do rowMeans() and sd(). How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.  I think using **dplyr** is probably the most straightforward, but you could also use the *tapply* command.  It's a little hard for me to figure out from your question which variables you want to group by, but hopefully running the following code will help make things clear --

Assuming you want to find the mean of var3, grouped by both var1 and var2, enter the following:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(var2,var1) %>% 
summarize(var3.mean = mean(var3))
```

like I said, it's a bit hard for me to tell whether this is the grouping structure you want.. the code above will give you the mean of var3 for each unique combination of var1 and var2.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says could not find the function %>%. Basically, I want to average all technical replicates. Each unique(var1) is matched with each unique(var2) and I have technical replicates for each combination.

Comment: Sorry -- I forgot to mention you'll need to install dplyr if you haven't already.  Before entering the code above, enter:  install.packages("dplyr").  Given the clarification, I'm fairly sure the code above should identify the means you're looking for.

Comment: I have it installed and just installed it again but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I found the problem. The function should be '%.%' instead of '%>%'. Thank you!

Comment: Gotcha.  %.% is the syntax for a slightly older version of the package -- this was just recently replaced about 2 months or so ago.

Answer (score 6):

In base R (calling your data frame `df`):

```
aggregate(var3~var1+var2,df,mean)
#    var1 var2     var3
# 1  AA.1    X 31.66667
# 2  AA.2    X 25.00000
# 3  AA.3    X 30.66667
# 4  BB.1    X 27.33333
# 5  BB.2    X 32.00000
# 6  BB.3    X 29.66667
# 7  AA.1    Y 32.33333
# 8  AA.2    Y 24.66667
# 9  AA.3    Y 26.66667
# 10 BB.1    Y 38.00000
# 11 BB.2    Y 30.33333
# 12 BB.3    Y 25.66667
```