# Using pattern to define biological sample replicates and calculating statitistics in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this one:

```
NAME VAL_1 VAL_2
Natural 2937,5  4082,5
Natural 3128    5347,5
Sus1    6176    7735,5
Sus1    8221    13793
Sus2    40961   68087
Sus2    6686    91341
```

As you can see, each row has two replicates, like `Natural`. My goal is to search in each row for the pattern that is repeated in each row and define that as a replicate. For example, find the pattern `Natural` and define both rows as replicates.

Based on that, I want to create new columns with some statistics. For example, the average between replicates.

```
| NAME    | VAL_1  | AVERAGE_1 | VAL_2 | AVERAGE_2 |
| Natural | 2937,5 | 3032,7 | 4082,5 | 4715,0 |
| Natural | 3128,0 | 3032,7 | 5347,5 | 4715,0 |
```

I think that one option to do that is to use regex to find a pattern on each row and define the replicates. For example:

```
grep(pattern="^Natural", 
    x=colnames(df_regex))
```

However, I think that is not the best option because, in my data frame, there are other rows that have a similar pattern, like `Natural1`, which could be a potential mix of data that are not necessarily biological replicate.

My first question:

Is this the best approach to define biological replicates in a data frame?
If the answer is no.

My second question:

Which other approach could I use to calculate the average between replicates?

Comment: You could compute the values grouped by column NAME easily with base R or dplyr as given explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580022/group-and-average-replicates-from-a-data-frame?rq=2), as well as with data.table. 
You could then join the grouped data.tables or tibbles to the original data.
The link also has a nice example of providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by *NAME* should do the trick

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("_\\d+"), 
    ~ mean(.x), .names="AVERAGES_{col}"), .by = NAME)
     NAME   VAL_1   VAL_2 AVERAGES_VAL_1 AVERAGES_VAL_2
1 Natural  2937.5  4082.5        3032.75        4715.00
2 Natural  3128.0  5347.5        3032.75        4715.00
3    Sus1  6176.0  7735.5        7198.50       10764.25
4    Sus1  8221.0 13793.0        7198.50       10764.25
5    Sus2 40961.0 68087.0       23823.50       79714.00
6    Sus2  6686.0 91341.0       23823.50       79714.00
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same but without specifying the name column? For example, I put ```VAL_1 or _2``` only to simplify the post. However, I have 100 columns with different names. So is it necessary to specify the name column?

Comment: @Mauri1313 No, you don't have to write out the name, you can also select by different specifications, e.g. `ends_with`, `starts_with`, `matches` etc. But to give a precise answer on that I'd need all the column names or at least a representative sample of them. With the given names I'd take `matches("\\d+$")`

Comment: Let me give you some column' names to simplify the example:
```
WT WTld WTsl WTfg WTss WTji Alpha_mm Alpha_qw Beta_mm Beta_qw```

Comment: @Mauri1313 I added way based on the given names in the example. You can also use `starts_with("W")` instead of `matches`, take a look here `?dplyr_tidy_select` to choose from the different options, something that fits your names.

Comment: @Mauri1313 ... as an idea, if you want to select everything but *NAME* you can do `across(!contains("NAME"), ~ ...`

Comment: Great, I think your approach is my answer. However, I have an issue with the col names that is not the topic of this post. So, I'm figuring out how to solve it first

Comment: Your approach works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

or using data.table, you could get what you ask for in one line of code after

`dt <- as.data.table(your_df)`

`dt[, c("average_1", "average_2") := list(mean(val_1), mean(val_2)), by = NAME]`

To answer your commend about 100 columns you could loop over all of these 100 column names something like this

```
for (colname in names(dt)[-1]) {
  newcolname <- paste0(colname, "_meanorwhatever")
  dt[, (newcolname) := mean(get(colname)), by = NAME]
}
```